# Unknown component in a shaded pole motor coil

Tags: components, induction-motor, coil

I dismantled a shaded pole motor and just found a component under the tape of the coil. It is placed in series with the copper wire. It is marked L120 Y068A3 (see picture). It comes from a breast pump made in Korea in the late 2000's. Any idea what is this component and what's its purpose?
[image: Dismantled shaded pole motor with a component marked L120 Y068A3]

Comment: Probably thermal fuse for winding protection.

Comment: I think this one is a thermostat type (self-resetting) overtemperature protector. You should leave it in place if you want to use the motor for something.

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea what is this component and what's its purpose?

It's a thermal cut-out, to cut power to the motor in the event of the motor getting too hot.

From its markings "L120 Y068A3" I expect it is designed to open at around 120 degrees C.

Some of these are effectively a thermal *fuse* and do not reset when the motor's temperature drops again; others contain a bi-metallic strip and those do reset as they cool.